# How to call a method from another class inside a Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, class

So I have a Class called "User" in which I have the following method and code:

```
public void Login()
{
   LoginWindow l = new LoginWindow();
   if (l.tbxEmail.Text != "" && l.tbxPassword.Text != "")
   {
      string query = "SELECT * FROM UsersTBL";
      l.con.Open();
      l.com = l.con.CreateCommand();
      l.com.CommandText = query;
      SqlDataReader dr = l.com.ExecuteReader();
      if (dr.Read())
      {
         if (dr["Email"].Equals(l.tbxEmail.Text.ToString()) && dr["UserPassword"].Equals(l.tbxPassword.Text.ToString()))
         {
            AppWindow a = new AppWindow();
            a.Show();
         }
         else
            l.lblMissingParameter.Content = "Incorrect Password or Email entered";
      }
   }
}
```

And in my LoginWindow I have:

```
public partial class LoginWindow:Window
{
     User u = new User();
     private void BtnSignup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         u.Login();
     }
}
```

When I try to call my Login method via class instantiation nothing works, why is that? Am I calling it the wrong way?

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean? What errorrs do you get (if any)?

Comment: So basically when i login with my email and pass it is supposed to open a new window "AppWindow" but that does not happen. When i hit the login button with my credentials entered in the textboxes. The App window does not pop up.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to see what happens? I suppose you have to **show** the login-dialog, not just **create** it.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `LoginWindow` in your `Login` method?

Comment: Couple things.  (1) you are only reading a single row from `UsersTBL`.  This code will fail when there is more than one user.  You can fix this by using `while (dr.Read())` and comparing all rows (or better yet, use `WHERE`).  (2) you should *never* store passwords as plain text.  They should be hashed, at the very least.

Comment: @Aars93 i am not creating a LoginWindow in my Login method, im creating a new App Window which should open after entering my details.

Comment: Try to pass the tbxEmail and tbxPassword as parameter for Login.

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel ok so your idea worked! I had to pass tbxEmail, tbxPass, SqlConnection con, SqlCommadn com as parameters for the Login method to work.

Comment: But what if I have a lot of variables that need to be passed as parameters for a method to work, wouldn't that be unnecessary and inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, although I left comments on things that should be addressed.

`User` class:

```
public bool Login(SqlConnection con, string email, string password)
{
    const string query = "SELECT 1 FROM UsersTBL WHERE Email = @email AND UserPassword = @password";
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            //Correct SqlDbTypes if necessary
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            //Should NOT be storing passwords as plain text in the database
            cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = password;
            if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             //log e somehow or eliminate this catch block
        }
        finally
        {
             //Close the connection if still open
             if (con != null && con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                 con.Close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`LoginWindow` class:

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    private void BtnSignup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var u = new User();
        if (u.Login(con, tbxEmail.Text, tbxPassword.Text))
        {
            AppWindow a = new AppWindow();
            a.Show();
        }
        else
            lblMissingParameter.Content = "Incorrect Password or Email entered";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you had this problem because the tbxEmail and tbxPassword variables in your User class where not the same as the ones in your main class.
You should create both variable at class scope:

```
public class User {

  TextBox tbxEmail; // could be strings
  PasswordBox tbxPassword;

  public User (TextBox tbxEmail, TextBox tbxPassword) {
    this.tbxEmail = tbxEmail;
    this.tbxPassword = tbxPassword;
  }
}
```

And then:

```
User user = new User(tbxEmail,tbxPassword);
user.Login();
```

Or, create a static method (static method can't use global variables, so everything you need have to be passed as parameter of the method or created inside of it).:

```
public static void Login (string email, string password){
  // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a rudimentary login page for one of my school projects similar to this:

```
private void signInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataProcedures data = new DataProcedures();
            User userInfo = new User(usernameTextbox.Text, passwordTextbox.Text);
            userInfo.userId = data.verifyUser(userInfo);

            if (userInfo.userId != -1)
            {
                AppWindow a = new AppWindow();
                 a.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                errorLabel.Show();
            }
        }

public int verifyUser(User userInfo)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            int userId = -1;

            string returnedUserName;
            string returnedPassword;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand checkUserNameCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                checkUserNameCmd.CommandText = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT userName FROM user WHERE userName = @username)";
                checkUserNameCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userInfo.username);
                returnedUserName = checkUserNameCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                MySqlCommand checkPasswordCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                checkPasswordCmd.CommandText = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT password FROM user WHERE BINARY password = @password AND userName = @username)";//"BINARY" is used for case sensitivity in SQL queries
                checkPasswordCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", userInfo.password);
                checkPasswordCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userInfo.username);
                returnedPassword = checkPasswordCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();



                if (returnedUserName == "1" && returnedPassword == "1")
                {
                    MySqlCommand returnUserIdCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    returnUserIdCmd.CommandText = "SELECT userId FROM user WHERE BINARY password = @password AND userName = @username";
                    returnUserIdCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", userInfo.password);
                    returnUserIdCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userInfo.username);
                    userId = (int)returnUserIdCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown verifying user: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return userId;
        }
```

Hope this helps.